# Assign Method to Action<string>

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, delegates

I have a class that has an `Action<string>` called `DisplayData`;

In various points in the class I call `DisplayData("Here's Data")`;

I have a Windows form with a method called `AddToList(string Data)`;

I have a main entry point class that has reference to my class and form and I am trying to do this:

```
fmMain MainForm = new fmMain();
MainForm.AddToList= Logic.DisplayData;
```

The idea is that when I call DisplayData in the various places in that class the form will display the data.

I assume the form has to have a action rather than a method but I'm not entirely sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it the wrong way round. You should use:

```
Logic.DisplayData = MainForm.AddToList;
```

(I'd also strongly suggest revisiting your names to follow .NET naming conventions, but that's a separate matter.)

Comment: What is badly named out of interest?

Comment: @Jon: You've got a variable using PascalCase, and a type using camelCase - and "frmMain" isn't even particularly descriptive to start with. How about naming it after what the application's actually about? :)

Comment: @Jon: you should take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
fmMain MainForm = new fmMain();
Logic.DisplayData+=MainForm.AddToList;
```

Comment: @Jon because it is not an event I wrote += !

Comment: @jon an event wont let you do `=`. a delegate will. I didnt want to take any chances ... so +=....

Comment: Ok thanks. In fact I just created an event on the form and used your syntax and it worked!